# Mocking AWS SDK's batchExecuteStatement in Jest for Unit Testing

Tags: testing, jestjs, aws-sdk

I'm writing unit tests for a function in Node.js, which utilizes AWS SDK's DynamoDB batchExecuteStatement method. Within this function, there's a certain logic which depends on the responses of the batchExecuteStatement.

My challenge lies in properly mocking batchExecuteStatement in Jest to mimic different response scenarios, specifically when it returns only errors or when it returns only successful results.

Could anyone guide me on how to correctly set up these mocks in Jest?

I have attempted to implement this in the following ways:

```
const Db = {
    batchExecuteStatement: jest.mockImplementation(() => {
        () => ({
            Responses: [],
        });
    }),
    test: 'true',
};

jest.mock('aws-sdk');
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
aws.DynamoDB.mockReturnValue(Db);


describe('retryFailed function', () => {


    it('should retry failedUsers', async () => {
        Db.batchExecuteStatement.mockReturnValue({
            promise: () => ({
                Responses: [
                    {Item: {UserAccountId: {S: 'id_1'}}},
                    {Item: {UserAccountId: {S: 'id_2'}}},
                ],
            }),
        });

        await retryFailed(faileUsersInput);
    });

});
```

and

```
describe('retryFailed function', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        jest.clearAllMocks();
    });

    it('should retry failedUsers', async () => {
        // Spy on batchExecuteStatement and provide new mock implementation
        jest.spyOn(DynamoDB, 'batchExecuteStatement').mockImplementation(() => ({
            promise: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({
                Responses: faileUsersInput.map((item) => {
                    return { userId: 'sssss' };
                }),
            }),
        }));

        await retryFailed(faileUsersInput);
        // add your expectations here
    });
});
```

However, these approaches haven't provided the desired outcome.

Thank you for your assistance.